# HTML5 shiv not working when DOCTYPE declared

Tags: internet-explorer, html

I can’t understand this. The HTML5 shiv is not working in IE 8 and lower when I declare the HTML5 doctype. It only works when there is no doctype. Why could this be? I have the shiv between the `<head>` tags, I have it before anything else (styles, other scripts) and it won’t work.

Generally the start of the page looks standard way like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <script src="/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to replicate your issue locally in IE8, and conclude that it's in the way you reference the `html5.js` file. Change your mark-up like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <script src="html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```

--i.e. remove the preceding "/" -- and all will be well. Worked for me. Counter-intuitive I grant you, but hey, welcome to the world of IE.

**EDIT** You say this still isn't working. This may be a daft question, but you *are* setting the HTML5 entities like `section`, `aside`, `header` etc. with the appropriate `display` attribute, aren't you? You don't provide the content of your stylesheet 'style.css' but you need to do this for things like `section`:

```
section {display: block}
```

Comment: Don’t tell me that it was such a stupid beginner mistake. :D Thank you very much, the edit of your answer gives the right clue. I didn’t have the entities set to display: block. Now it’s OK. :)

Answer (score 1):

Modernizer is also worth a try if your still having problems..

[Modernizer Homepage](http://www.modernizr.com/)

Comment: Already tried and the same problem occured. I tried to Google the web top to bottom but haven’t found single mention of the problem I encounter.

Comment: I know this may sound strange, have you tired displaying a js alert anywhere on the page.. is JS running?

Answer (score 0):

Manipulate the shiv, and put an `alert('something')` in it. See if it alerts anything or not. If not, then it's not executed, and we should see why. If yes, then maybe it's corrupt. Download the latest version from [here](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/).
Use [this shiv](http://www.thoughtresults.com/scripts/ie-html5.js)

Comment: Well, actually I was linking right to the shiv on the web. I downloaded it and tried to add the alert and it was processed right and alerted when the page was run.

Comment: @josefec: “Well, actually I was linking right to the shiv on the web.” Maybe that was the problem? The code you’ve posted doesn’t link to the HTML5 shiv on the web.

Comment: Yes, that’s how I’ve rewritten it and now I have the shiv downloaded and loading locally. But it hasn’t helped.

Comment: Create a sample test page. Add html5 shiv to it and write a simple <article> element inside body. See if it works or not. If not, I think there is a problem with your IE. Try to reinstall it.

Comment: OK, I did create a sample page and also put it on the web so you can see it: http://beta.drevic-rokytnik.cz/indexa.php. I also tried the NetRenderer and it also shows nothing in the case of this page, so it can’t be caused by my IE.

Comment: I think this version is not working because of conditional compile. I'll try to find another version for you :), or you can take the code out of conditional compile block. Use [this](http://www.thoughtresults.com/scripts/ie-html5.js) shiv.

Comment: Really, really strange because it’s still working only without the doctype declaration. Let’s see: http://beta.drevic-rokytnik.cz/indexb.php